# Orthogonal projection in complex Hilbert space

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a complex Hilbert space, and let $T\in L(X, X)$ denote the orthogonal
projection onto a closed subspace $M ⊆ X$.

(a) Determine the kernel $N(T − λI)$ and the range $R(T − λI)$ of $T − λI$ for
each $λ ∈ C$.

(b) Find all $λ ∈ C$ for which $T − λI$ has an inverse $(T − λI)^{−1}$ in $L(X, X)$. Justify your answer.

(c) What is the spectrum of $T − λI$?

I thought of this problem for quite sometime, but couldn't solve any of the three parts above. For part $(a)$, for the kernel, I know that we need to solve: $(T - \lambda I) x$ $= 0$. But how to show that $T - \lambda I$ is invertible by using the hypothesis that T is orthogonal projection so that we can get $x = 0$?

I completely got stuck on the remaining parts, so can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: Why would you want to show that $T-\lambda I$ is invertible?

Comment: Because then $x = 0$ is the only solution in the kernel. Otherwise, there might be infinitely many solutions?

Comment: OK, so showing that $T-\lambda I$ is invertible will tell you that the kernel is $\{0\}$. So it'll work in that case. But if the kernel isn't $\{0\}$, then you'll be out of luck, so I just meant to say that it seemed to be a strange first step. But, you're in luck: for most $\lambda$, $T-\lambda I$ will in fact be invertible. Here's a hint: if (for example) $\lambda=5$ and $(T-\lambda I)x=0$, what does that tell you about $Tx$ and $\lambda x$?

Comment: It would tell me $Tx$ is a $1-1$ and onto linear transformation mapping $x$ to $5x$, or $\lambda x$. In that case, the kernel is definitely $\left\{0\right\}$, so by Rank-Nullity Theorem, $R(T-\lambda I) = dim(X)$. But $T$ is an orthogonal projection implies what property?

Comment: $T$ wouldn't need to map all $x$ to $5x$ – just those $x$ that are in the kernel. But when is an orthogonal projection going to send a vector to a multiple of itself? For example, consider the projection from $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ to $\{(x,y,0)|x,y\in\mathbb{R}\}$. What vectors does that projection send to scalar multiples of themselves?

Comment: Regards to your question and your example in $R^3$, it would be $(1,1,0)$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26104/discussion-between-ben-whitney-and-user177196).

Comment: when you want to calculate $P(x)$ where $P$ is a projection operator : you decompose $x$ as $x = y+z$ where $y$ belongs to the kernel of $P$, whereas $z$ is $\perp$ to the kernel, then $P(x) = z$, so the eigenvalues of $P$ must be $0$ and $1$....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An orthogonal projection satisfies $T^{2}=T^{\star}=T$. For $\lambda\notin\{0,1\}$, you can explictly solve the following for $x$.
$$
                     (T-\lambda I)x = y.
$$
First, apply $T$ to both sides
$$
                 (1-\lambda)Tx = Ty
$$
Then apply $(I-T)$ to both sides
$$
               -\lambda(I-T)x = (I-T)y
$$
Therefore,
$$
   x = Tx +(I-T)x = \frac{1}{1-\lambda}Ty-\frac{1}{\lambda}(I-T)y
$$
You can verify that, for $\lambda\notin\{0,1\}$,
$$
       (T-\lambda I)\left[\frac{1}{1-\lambda}T-\frac{1}{\lambda}(I-T)\right]=I,\\
        \left[\frac{1}{1-\lambda}T-\frac{1}{\lambda}(I-T)\right](T-\lambda I)=I
$$

Comment: thank you for your help. I wonder what if $\lambda = 0$ or $1$? And is the range in the case of   $\lambda\neq \left\{0, 1\right\}$ would be $dim(X)-1$? Can you also help with parts (b) and (c)?

Comment: @user177196 : $x = (I-T)x+Tx$ and $(I-T)x \perp Tx$. There are two trivial cases to discuss first: $T=I$ and $T=0$. Other than that, both $T$ and $I-T$ have non-trivial null spaces, and the ranges of these two are mutually orthogonal, i.e., $X = TX\oplus (I-T)X$. See if you can work out the remaining details from this.

Comment: for part (b), if $\lambda=0$ or $1$, then $T - \lambda I$ has non-trivial kernel, so it doesn't have inverse. When $\lambda \neq 0, 1$, you solved it above. For part (c), if $z$ is in the spectrum of $T-\lambda I$, then  $T-\lambda I-zI$ is not invertible. Using part (b), this occurs when $\lambda - z = 0$ or $1$, so $z = \lambda$ or $z = \lambda - 1$. Is this solution correct?

Comment: @user177196 ... when $\lambda+z = 0$ or $1$, so $z=-\lambda$ or $z=1-\lambda$. Sign error. Everything else looks correct.

Comment: @user177196 : It's worth mentioning that $\mathcal{R}(T)=M$ and $\mathcal{R}(I-T)=M^{\perp}$. Don't forget the special cases where $M=\{0\}$ and $M=X$, which is where $T=0$ and $T=I$, respectively.

Comment: thank you very much for your detailed help. I appreciate it. But isn't it the case that when $T=0$ we also have $R(T)=M$ as well, since $T=0$ corresponds to $\lambda = 0$?

Comment: @user177196 : Keep in mind that the spectrum is different in the special cases.

Comment: that's true. Is the spectrum $z=0$ in both special cases?

Comment: @user177196 : $\sigma(0)=\{0\}$ and $\sigma(I)=\{1\}$.