# spectrum of an orthogonal projection

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory, orthogonality

Let $H$ be a $\mathbb C$-Hilbert space and $A\in\mathfrak L(H)$ with $A^2=A=A^\ast$.

> Let $\lambda\in\mathbb C$ and $x,y\in H$ with $(\lambda-A)x=y$. How can we solve this for $x$?

I've stumbled about [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1369507/47771), which is showing how e can do this. However, I don't get one step in the description.

First, we can multiply both sides by $A$. Using that $A^2=A$, we obtain $$(\lambda-1)Ax=Ay\tag1.$$ But now the author of the post is multiplying both sides of $(1)$ by $A-1$. I don't get that since with this multiplication, bot sides of $(1)$ should simply vanish. For example, $$(A-1)Ay=Ay-A^2y=Ay-Ay=0\tag2.$$ What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author didn‘t multiply both  sides of (1) with $A - 1$ - as you pointed out correctly this gives $0= 0$, but he multiplied the equation he started with $(\lambda - A)x = y$ with $A-1$.

Comment: Oh, my ... Well, I've completely misunderstood that.

Comment: Just one more thing: In general, if $T$ is a bounded linear operator on a Banach space, we've always got $\mathcal N(T)\subseteq\mathcal R(1-T)$ and $\mathcal N(1-T)\subseteq\mathcal R(T)$, right? And if $T$ is an projection (i.e. $T^2=T$), then it even holds equality, right? I'm asking cause I've only seen these statement in the context of orthogonal projections on Hilbert spaces, but they should hold in the general case as I wrote above, right?

Comment: Sure. If $Tx = 0$, then $(1-T)x = x$. And if $(1-T)x = 0$, then $x = Tx$.